# Define methods in template class in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

I am making a template class which has variable template arguments. However, when I define and call a method, my compiler says the method is not defined.

```
template <class T, class... Args>
class Params {
private:
    vector<void*> params;
    int n;

    void initializeParam(T a, Args... args) {
        params[n] = (void*)&a;
        n++;
        initializeParam(args...);
    }

    void initializeParam() {}

public:
    Params(T a, Args... args) : params(vector<void*>(sizeof...(Args))) {
        n = 0;
        initializeParam(a, args...); // Compiler -> initializeParam is not defined
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: And if you're getting an error, post the most relevant parts from it as well.

Comment: why using a void*?

Answer (score 2):

Try rewriting the main `initializeParams()` as follows

```
template <typename U, typename ... As>
void initializeParam(U a, As... args) {
    params[n++] = (void*)&a;
    initializeParam(args...);
}
```

Your current `initializeParams()` is called from the constructor but when try to call itself recursively there isn't an `initializeParams()` with correct arguments.

So you have to separate the template arguments of the class from the template arguments for `initializeParams()`